# Modern word for a "New Age hippie"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes the modern version of the New Age hippie; the kind of person taken in by things that were previously associated with the New Age movement, like "alternative" medicine and general pseudoscience. I was previously considering using "New-Age spiritualists", but this is probably not accurate anymore since the New Age movement is technically dead.

Comment: Is [New Age](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/New_Age) really dead? It has faded a bit compared to other concepts like wellness/wellbeing, wicca, neopaganism, environmentalism, and various other specific practices. There has also been a division into far-left vegan environmentalists and right-wing trust-nobody COVID-denying GM=NWO conspiracy theorists (sometimes embracing neo-Norse religion etc). I agree that "spiritualists" is wrong because it commonly refers to what is also called "spiritism" i.e. mediumistic communication with the dead. But New Age is still fine.

Comment: Or do you just want a noun that's not "hippy" to use with New Age, like "New Ager" or "New Age conspiracy nut"?

Comment: "Post-New Age Hippie" or "Next-Gen Hippie"

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the poster has failed to give an example sentence in which they would use the word.

Comment: @StuartF Good point about spiritualists, I didn't think the word was that associated with mediums but I should probably avoid it. And you're right, I'm probably looking more for a synonym of hippie than I am of New Age.

Comment: @Prometheus I require nothing - the rules (which you may consult) require it. A moment's thought would demonstrate why the rule is a good one.